# How can add posts without category into category

Tags: posts, taxonomy

I have some posts in my wordpress without category, Its above 2000 article, So i need to add this article into category that name is " News "

Comment: You can rename the Uncategorized category to News?

Comment: thankx but the post not have any category, its not have any value